# Format cells based on input in multiple other cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

The purpose of the sheet in question is to allow a group of people working on a project to see who is responsible for what task on what date. To achieve this, there are:

- three columns: D (`task responsibility`), E (`start date`), F (`end date`)
- multiple columns starting at G: each designating one day, ie G is `17-Feb`, H is `18-Feb` etc.
- a number of rows, each assigned a specific task

For instance pertaining to task X:

- cell C5 denotes the task (irrelevant here)
- cell D5 denotes the person that is responsible for the task. If it is, say, `B`, certain cells from G5 onwards (H5, I5, etc), should be filled with color purple, but
- only the cells should be filled within the respective time period as set in cell E (`start date`) and F (`end date`), ie if the start date is 17-Feb (cell G3) and the end date is 18-Feb (cell H3), G5 and H5 should be purple.
- Each person should be allocated a different color.

I'm not very experienced with Excel but willing to learn, that's why I turn to you. I was experimenting with conditional formatting and also a little bit of VBA, but I'm not there yet. This is why I would be most grateful for your help. I have researched the forum, and continue to find hints that may be of help, so I'll keep trying.

[image: SO21706949 question example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try a series of Conditional Formatting rules (choose the colour according to the value in ColumnD) of this kind:

```
=AND(G$3>=$E5,G$3<=$F5)
```

with Applies to: =$G$5:however far across you wish, for the same row.

Comment: Thanks very much! This did the date part of the job. Now, I'm not sure how to combine a second rule that makes the colour dependent on the input in cell D5.

Comment: Is it not possible to achieve with conditional format that the cells are filled according to the start and end dates with a colour dependent on the input in a third cell?

Comment: One way to acheive this would be to have three separate rules -- one for each color, each with a condition added to the `AND` formula @pnuts has shown that refers to the third cell -- for example, `=AND($D5="B",G$3>=$E5,G$3<=$F5)` for purple.

Comment: @pnuts, if you include the extra condition you can apply the same three rules to all rows -- you don't need to "know" which rule to apply to which row.